# Printing documents from a hyperlink in excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

i am trying to create a VBA code to open a hyperlink in a cell, (This cells hyperlink changes depending on other variables in the spreadsheet, but i don't believe that matters)

Basically i want to press the macro, it will open the hyperlink, which could either be a document in excel or word, i then want it to print that document by an amount specified in a different cell in the same spreadsheet as the hyperlink.

I also want the document to not pop up, or at least close after printing has finished.

The printer it would need to print from is called SRV-papercut1

I have been attempting to code it myself, but cant quite manage, Any ideas?

**Amount cell**: J20 **Hyperlink Cell:** O18

I have attached a photo of the spreadsheet so you can see it.(I have cut off the company logo on the left for privacy reasons) [One Button Print Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFh8P.png)

Comment: `I have been attempting to code it myself` .... show us your code. You may be closer than you think but more importantly, it shows us that you made an attempt and means people don't have to start from 0

Comment: Think about the actions that need to happen as individual steps. How to do each of those individual steps is well documented on this site from other peoples questions. Have you tried to research the individual components of your task and modify/bring them together to fit your unique problem?

Comment: "The printer it would need to print from is called SRV-papercut1" <-- share the code that can do this (without any dependencies, just plain simple print.).. then we can proceed from there I guess.. /(^_^)